# Как закрыть UIViewController после появления UIAlertController?

Tags: swift, uikit

Всем привет! Такая ситуация -

У меня `UIViewController`, который презентуется модально (present modally). В конце всех мне нужных действий появляется `UIAlertController`. После его появления, либо же после нажатия на кнопку "OK", я хочу закрыть этот `UIViewController`. Метод `self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)` срабатывает, но срабатывает он именно на сам `UIAlertController` .

Допустим, вот метод -

```
func showAlertAndDismiss() {
savePost(previewPost: previewPost!, completion: { (success) in
      if success {

       let alertOK = UIAlertController(title: "Пост опубликован", message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
       let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil)
       alertOK.addAction(okAction)

       self.present(alertOK, animated: true, completion: nil)
       self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Закрывается только сам `AlertController`, а не `UIViewController`
В хендлере `UIAlertAction` также пробовал вставлять `self.dismiss`, но убирается только алерт. Как быть?

Мне не важно когда `UIViewController` закроется - после появления `UIAlertController`, или после нажатия на кнопку OK. Главное закрыть `ViewController`

Answer (score 1):

Быстро набросал, но все работает, как надо. Проверь, где у тебя ошибка.
Вот первый ВьюКонтроллер

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 250, width: 150, height: 50))
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(presentViewController), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.backgroundColor = .green
        view.addSubview(button)
    }

    @objc private func presentViewController() {
        let viewController = SecondViewController()
        present(viewController, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Вот второй ВьюКонтроллер.

```
final class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 250, width: 150, height: 50))
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(presentViewController), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.backgroundColor = .green
        view.addSubview(button)
    }

    @objc private func presentViewController() {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { _ in
            self.dismiss(animated: true)
        }
        alertController.addAction(action)
        present(alertController, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Никаких сторибордов и других сетапов.

Comment: Привет! Огромное спасибо за ответ! Вот что заметил - self.dismiss(animated: true) у меня просто не выполняется. Брейк-поинт не срабатывает

Answer (score 0):

Очень просто по нажатию на ОК

```
let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default) { (UIAlertAction) in
     self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Я писал выше, что в хендлере я уже прописывал так. Он закрывает только UIAlertController

Comment: @Gatsby у меня срабатывает, специально смоделировал вашу ситуацию

Comment: @Gatsby на какой версии iOS вы тестировали?